# Confidence Intervals of a one sided truncated normal distribution

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, expected-value, truncated-normal-distribution

Assume $y\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ it can be shown that UMP alpha ($\alpha$) level tests are derived from the $\alpha/2$ quantiles i.e. $z(\alpha/2)$

How can we find confidence intervals of a truncated normal distribution, truncated on being greater than zero, 
$P(y|y>0)=A(\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma})/(1-A(\frac{0-\mu}{\sigma}))$ where $A$ is the CDF of a standard normal variable.

The aim here is to find a confidence interval around the mean i.e. Expectation of $P(y|y>0)$

Comment: What quantity is it you seek a CI for?

Comment: @Glen_b I want a confidence interval for the Epectation of P(y|y>0)

Comment: The opening reads like a textbook style problem -- is this a question for a class? What is $P$ intended to represent here? A cdf?

Comment: @Glen_b Hello p here is probability, This is not atext book question it is a common engineering problem that I currently faced in my research. Example: in engineering systems some performance indicators like throughput cannot take negative values , thus it might be a challenge to model them as normal variables

Comment: 1. $P$ is the probability of what event? What you have on the left side of the "|" is "y"; if you mean $Y=y$, this has probability $0$. If you mean $Y\leq y$ then that would be the cdf of the truncated variable.. 2. If your variables cannot be normal, they're also unlikely to be truncated normal. why not choose models that are non-negative to begin with (say, Gamma, Weibull, lognormal, ... there are many possible models to choose from, depending on what you know about your process). Some (including all three that I just mentioned) can be very close to normal in appearance.